# Count how many named columns in CSV [python pandas]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv that has 'headers' that looks kind of like this:

```
name, id, avoid1, avoid2, avoid3, avoidN, choice1, choice2, choice3, choiceN
```

The number of choice  and avoid columns is not a known amount. It can possibly only have one choice1, or it can go up to choice100. Same for avoid. They will always be labeled choiceN and avoidN.

I want to know how to determine how many 'choice' columns there are and how many 'avoid' columns there are. They probably will each have a different amount of columns, meaning just because choiceN goes up to choice5, doesn't mean avoid will go up to avoid5, it can be avoid2 or avoid20. The closest I got was counting all the columns using:

```
print(df.count(axis='columns'))
```

but that just tells me how many total columns there are, which only brings me a third way there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with columns names, remove non matched values by [`Index.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.dropna.html) and last use [`Index.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.value_counts.html):

```
print (df.columns.str.extract('(avoid|choice)', expand=False).dropna().value_counts())
choice    4
avoid     4
dtype: int64
```